# Migrating MySQL query to Oracle 12c syntax

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration, oracle12c

Hello I have already refer this link

[Translating MySQLqueries into HSQLDB and Oracle queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802209/translating-mysqlqueries-into-hsqldb-and-oracle-queries)

But I have not found anything useful,
the problem is I want to migrate MYSQL DB --> ORACLE 12c DB.
But problem is migration is done successfully using oracle SQL Developer, but when I try to login user then it gives me not error invalid credentials
For Eg:-If i have migrated "testdb " schema then in ORacle testdb user and testdb as  password, but it is not able to logged in.
So in short I am very very much struck to resolve this

Comment: Cant log in to new database after migration

Comment: what is the oracle error message?

Answer (score 0):

No sure, but I have seen issues when you have set up Oracle 12c in pluggable database mode. You have to change the connection to localhost:1521/YOUR_DATABASE instead of localhost:1521.

Comment: Yes in oracle 12c I have found CDB and PDB..I don't know what is this and what are difference between this.can u share some Good link to throw some light on this.Between I am newbie to Oracle12C so I found out this thing very complex,in comparision to MYSQL AND MSSQL